# How to use dbt seed properly with dbt-spark[PyHive] running in EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, dbt, pyhive

## Problem

I am trying to implement a new process using dbt seeds. When I use it in a Redshift connection there is no problem, but when I try to use it with dbt-spark[PyHive] in EMR some problems arise.

## First Try

```
seed-paths: ["seeds"]

seeds:
      dock_analytics_spark:
        seed:
          location_root: s3://dock-analytics/seeds/
```

Using the code above in the dbt_project.yml I receive the following error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "dbfs"

## Second Try

```
seed-paths: ["seeds"]

seeds:
  dock_analytics_spark:
    +materialized: table
    +schema: seed
    +file_format: parquet
    +location_root: s3://dock-analytics/seeds/
```

Using the code above in the dbt_project.yml I receive the following error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input
> 'None' expecting {'(', 'FROM', 'MAP', 'REDUCE', 'SELECT', 'TABLE',
> 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 14, pos 6)
>
> == SQL == /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "1.0.4", "profile_name": "dock_spark", "target_name": "dev", "node_id":
> "seed.dock_analytics_spark.seed_pos_eny_mde_pan_cde"} */
>
> ```
>   create table dock_analytics_seed.seed_pos_eny_mde_pan_cde
>
>
> using parquet
>
>
>
>
> location 's3://dock-analytics/seeds//seed_pos_eny_mde_pan_cde'
>
> as
>   None
> ```
>
> ------^^^

Someone knows how to properly use dbt seed with dbt-spark[PyHive] running in EMR?

Answer (score 0):

edit 1:
The error was caused by the materialized config. If you're storing the seed into hdfs, you should not use it. Or you can use it but not with the location_root config, which means the seed will be stored locally.

Original:
I'm not sure if you've figured this out or not. Just posting here for anyone else that running into this error. The AS statement needs a parameter from the profile to set the name for the seed table. This parameter should be specified explicitly like this:

```
seeds:
    tabel_name:
        +materialized: table
        +file_format: delta
        +location_root: 'hdfs://xxxxx'
```